# Get last n group of numbers in a loop

Tags: php, loops

I have a loop, the loop is like there are 4 items in each row, i want to add class to the elements of the last row so i need something like this :

```
switch( $count ){
    case 8:
        $items = [5, 6, 7, 8];
        break;

    case 7:
        $items = [5, 6, 7];
        break;

    case 6:
        $items = [5, 6];
        break;

    case 5:
        $items = [5];
        break;

    case 9:
        $items = [9];
        break;

    case 10:
        $items = [9, 10];
        break;

    case 11:
        $items = [9, 10, 11];
        break;

    case 12:
        $items = [9, 10, 11, 12];
        break;

    case 13:
        $items = [13];
        break;

    // And so on...

    default:
        if( $count <= 4 ){
            $items = range(1, $count);
        }
        break;
}
```

I think using `switch` statement is not the proper way to do this, besides it works only for `$count` numbers less than 14 and if i would have to write all numbers one by one if i want to get it worked with no matter what `$count` value is.

**To clearify a little bit more :**

We have a set of items ( html elements ), which there are 4 of them in each row, and we want to add a css class to each item in the last row,
so if the total items count is 8 , the 5th, 6th, 7th and 8th items are in the last row.

See thse examples

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8  This is the last row, so $items equals [5, 6, 7, 8]

OR 

1   2   3   4
5   6          This is also the last row so $items equals [5, 6]

OR

1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11      This is last row too  so $items equals [9, 10, 11]

OR

1   2   3   4   We have only 4 items , so there is only one row so $items equals [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I feel like this could do with some context for clarity ... what *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: what are you expecting the output to look like. I have no idea what you want.

Comment: @DevDonkey i want to find index number of elements in the last row, each row contains 4 items, so if total number is 8 then last row index numbers will be [5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: So why doesn't  `7` generate `4, 5, 6, 7` ???

Comment: @AbraCadaver `4` is in the first row , 5 and 6 and 7 are in the second row, as i said each row has 4 elements

Comment: Edited the question with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was working on something with `range()` and had to slice it:

```
$items = array_slice(range($count - 3, $count), -($count % 4));
```

Then I asked, why couldn't I do it in the `range()`:

```
$items = range($count - ($count - 1) % 4, $count);
```

Comment: Short and nice answer, i think the `array_slice(range($count-3, $count), -($count%4))` will do it alone

Comment: That's different than your question but OK.

Comment: It's not ,if i added some examples to the question, if you see them, your code gives the result i want

Comment: OK, in that case I added an easier one.

Answer (score 4):

I do not understand why 1, 2, 3, 4 are separate from the rest, but since that is what you seem to want, this is your solution:

```
if( $count <= 4 ){
    $items = [1, 2, 3, 4];
} else {
    $items = [] ;
    for ( $i = $count - ($count-1) % 4 ; $i <= $count  ; $i++) {
        $items[] = $i ;
    }
}
```

Comment: when there is less than 5 elements, then we only have 1 row, so the first row is also the last row

Comment: This is one of those cases that what you explain seems completely logical, and obviously, it is to you, yet for us (at least me), it somehow just doesn't land. We don't get it. Anyway, the results of the code are the same as in your code, so I guess that doesn't matter. ;)

Comment: yeah, sorry i couln't explain it well but your code is exactly what i needed, you don't even need the first `if` statement, it works for all numbers

Comment: As long as you know exactly what you are doing, and why, you are fine ;) Glad I could help.

Comment: Thank you Roemer, you can edit the answer and remove the `if` statement

Comment: I'll leave it there since that's the way it produces exactly the same result as your code; in your own code of course you do whatever you like ;). Cheers!

Comment: @Amin: When `$count=1` you get only `[1]` but you show `[1,2,3,4]` is what you expect.

Comment: @AbraCadaver That's even better, because 2,3,4 don't exist. i have wrote the code wrong